# how to layout with right position

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a screen and it is
[image]
i want the buttons to put under each other and the text view under each over , my code is

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LL1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTab1Ask"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="ask for new question" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bMainTabsGetQuestion"
                            android:layout_width="116dp"
                            android:layout_height="33dp"
                            android:text="Get Question"
                            android:textSize="15px" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LL2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTab1Join"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Join New Competition" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bMainTabsJoin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:text="Join"
                            android:textSize="15px" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LL3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTab1Signout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="or you can signout" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bMainTabsSignout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:text="Sign out"
                            android:textSize="15px" />
                    </LinearLayout>
```

i mean each button have to start vertically at the same point

Comment: Better to user RelativeLayout

Comment: <TableLayout> is batter option for "Form" type UI

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani when i tried it , the butom becomes up and the textview down

Comment: Add your new TableLayout XML to the question so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try followin XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Ask for new Question"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="Get Questiopn"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Join new Competition"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="Join"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Or you can Signout"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:text="Sign Out"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

It is perfectly working, see followin

[image]

Comment: but layout_colum not found :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that when you will make it with `<TableLayout>` it will works how you want.

Comment: do u mean that i have to replace linerlayout with tablelayout?

Comment: when i did that the button become up and the textview become dowmn

Comment: in one row, you should have text and button.

Comment: ok...for futur don't asking me for details when you will accept other answer that wrote some like me.

Comment: i accepted his/her answer because i just copied paste his code cos i am new on android, any way very thanks to you, and sorry

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to change orientation to **vertical**(something like `android:orientation="vertical"`) of each linear layout if you want to set the buttons and texts vertically ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of LinearLayout

and use parameters like `android:layout_alignLeft=""
                            android:layout_alignBottom=""` to align it according to your designs.